# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() simple_html_dom.php on line 1119

Tags: php, oop, dom, pthreads, simple-html-dom

here is what im doing
im using

- pthreads from -  pthreads.org
- php Simple Html DOM parser from - simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

now the process of what i (will) do is:

1. I am reading a bulk of links that is from a text file.
2. I initialize a thread to have a separate process
3. I am creating a log file for this thread so that i will know, what happens later on.

now, this is my code for my thread class.

```
class ReadLinks extends Thread {

private $conn;
private $links;
private $fileObj;

public function __construct($conn, $links, $fileObj) {
    //.. well just asign this to the global variables
}

public function run() {
    try {
        $this->logMsg("Start Reading Reviews");
        $this->readLinks();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $this->logMsg($ex);
    }
    $this->closeLog();
}

private function readLinks() {
    $this->logMsg("Links");
    foreach ($this->links as $link) {
        $link = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $link));
        $this->logMsg("Link: " . $link);
        $html = html_readLink($link);
       break;
    }
}

private function logMsg($msg) {//something to write on the text file
}

private function closeLog() {//closes the textfile
}}
```

$conn - is my mysqli link to have db actions in the future

$links - is an array of links to be read.

$fileObj- is a resource return from fopen(). ( well to write into a file)

now who is that html_readlink,
its an outer function that is like this:

```
function html_readLink($link) {
    return file_get_html($link);}
```

basically it is the resource returned by a function from simple html dom parser

now, i have as well a function that reads a link alone to do the other (different business requirement) and im using the simple html dom parser with ease.

with the pthreads, i tried writing the file(logs first) so that i can ensure that everything as well works fine.
about contacting db is not yet sure., well ill try to figure it out if it works fine, but logically it should work.

now when i called this class: its like this:

```
try {
    $thread = new readLinks($conn, $Links, createlog());
    if ($thread->start()) {
        $thread->join();
    } else {
        echo "something i need to research if this happens";
    }
} catch (Exception $err) {
    echo $err; //something i need to research as well if this happens
}
```

i got this error

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\my\path\to\simplehtmldom_1_5\simple_html_dom.php on line 1119
```

that simplehtmldom code is:

```
function clear()
{
    foreach ($this->nodes as $n) {$n->clear(); $n = null;}
    // This add next line is documented in the sourceforge repository. 2977248 as a fix for ongoing memory leaks that occur even with the use of clear.
    if (isset($this->children)) foreach ($this->children as $n) {$n->clear(); $n = null;}
    if (isset($this->parent)) {$this->parent->clear(); unset($this->parent);}
    if (isset($this->root)) {$this->root->clear(); unset($this->root);}
    unset($this->doc);
    unset($this->noise);
}
```

now that is the source code coming from simple html dom. that foreach is the one that is returning the error. now my other code using simple html dom doesn't have a problem with simple html dom. but with pthreads i got this error.

also, when i change my codes and didn't use pthreads, (had some revisions like this:
on pthreads class:

```
class ReadLinks {// extends Thread {
//insert other codes
public function readLinks() {
        $this->logMsg("Links");
        foreach ($this->links as $link) {
            $link = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $link));
            $this->logMsg("Link: " . $link);
            $html = html_readLink($link);
            $this->logMsg(getTitle($html));
//           
            break;
        }
    }
```

and change the way this is called like this:

```
try {
        $thread = new ReadLinks($conn, $revLinks, createlog());
        $thread->readLinks();
//        if ($thread->start()) {
//            $thread->join();
//        } else {
//            echo "something i need to research if this happens";
//        }
    } catch (Exception $err) {
        echo $err; //something i need to debug and research if this happens
    }
```

everything works fine, i get the desired results.

pthreads is something i need to use since loading bulk links and reading each of them is quite a time consuming process. and i need it to be on a separate thread. now i dont know whats wrong with these pthreads, or simple html dom parser. have i done something unnecessary/wrong? is there other way to do this?

anyone??

---

**EDIT**

i followed the answer of Prafulla Kumar Sahu:
the new code for the function clear() of simple html dom is:

```
function clear() {
    if (is_array($this->nodes) || $this->nodes instanceof Traversable) {
        foreach ($this->nodes as $n) {
            $n->clear();
            $n = null;
        }
    }
    // This add next line is documented in the sourceforge repository. 2977248 as a fix for ongoing memory leaks that occur even with the use of clear.
    if (isset($this->children))
        foreach ($this->children as $n) {
            $n->clear();
            $n = null;
        }
    if (isset($this->parent)) {
        $this->parent->clear();
        unset($this->parent);
    }
    if (isset($this->root)) {
        $this->root->clear();
        unset($this->root);
    }
    unset($this->doc);
    unset($this->noise);
}
```

the result is: **it eliminated the error**
but it is **not the desired result**
when using the function

```
$x=$resource->find($selector,0); 
//resource is the return obj of file_gets_content, selector is my css selector string
```

it returns null/empty where in fact it should have a value.

ive checked a separate function that uses the simple html dom after i updated their code, seems it wasn't affected, and it is working properly. but with my pthread class, it is not working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The code I have doesn't have a foreach on line 1119; maybe you have an older version. You're getting a warning only, what problem(s) do you see in the results?

```
1117    // save dom as string
1118    function save($filepath='')
1119    {
1120        $ret = $this->root->innertext();
1121        if ($filepath!=='') file_put_contents($filepath, $ret, LOCK_EX);
1122        return $ret;
1123    }
```

Comment: hi thanks, for the answer, please check:
https://github.com/jalbertbowden/simplehtmldom/blob/master/simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php#L1119 for the line 1119 error, and if you have any other way to deal with this, please update. thanks, :)

Answer (score 0):

It happens if the variable you are trying to traverse using `foreach` is not `irritable` so please check if your variable is either an `array` or  `instanceof Traversable`  class .

*It may be because you are not getting any value for that variable you want to traverse.

so, I would suggest you to use `is_array( $whatever ) || $whatever instanceof Traversable` just before foreach.

ie.

```
if( is_array( $whatever ) || $whatever instanceof Traversable ){
    foreach( $whatever as $what ){
       //some code
    }
}
```

In your case it is

```
   function clear()
    {
        foreach ($this->nodes as $n) {$n->clear(); $n = null;}
        // This add next line is documented in the sourceforge repository. 2977248 as a fix for ongoing memory leaks that occur even with the use of clear.
        if (isset($this->children)) foreach ($this->children as $n) {$n->clear(); $n = null;}
        if (isset($this->parent)) {$this->parent->clear(); unset($this->parent);}
        if (isset($this->root)) {$this->root->clear(); unset($this->root);}
        unset($this->doc);
        unset($this->noise);
    }
```

source:- https://github.com/jalbertbowden/simplehtmldom/blob/master/simplehtmldom_1_5/simple_html_dom.php#L1119

this means you are unable to get $this->nodes correctly, so please var_dump it before you are calling function clear or before the foreach .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
Ive followed your example, and inserted an if statement before the foreach. result is that: it does not show the error anymore, but that is not the desired result, it is returning null/empty where in fact it should not be empty. ive run a separate function that uses the simple html dom after i updated their code, seems, it wasn't affected, and it is working properly. but with my pthread class, it does not working correctly

Comment: I have explained how you should use foreach and after that I have also said what problem you are facing,  I have never used simple_html_dom , I have only described your problem and solution based on core PHP, so that it will be helpful to you as well as other people who will come across it.